# data not filtering in ajax codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I want to filter data by dropdown but it giving me all data....

this is my model with ajax function

```
public function ajax()
{
     $query = "SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'"; 
    if(!empty($size)){
        $query  .= " and city in('".$size."')"; 
    }
    if(!empty($sprice) && !empty($eprice)){
        $query  .=  " and charge_per_hour >='".$sprice."' and 
        charge_per_hour <='".$eprice."'"; 
    }

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result();   
}
```

And this is my controller

```
public function ajax()
{

    $size = $this->input->post('size');
    $sprice = $this->input->post('sprice');
    $eprice = $this->input->post('eprice');

    $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    $result = $this->ajax_model->ajax();


    foreach( $result as $row )
    {   
        echo $row->name.'<br>'; 
        echo $row->charge_per_hour.'<br>'; 
        echo $row->city.'<br>'; 
    }
}
```

This is it looks after running code...

it giving me all data instead of selected data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ3Ur.png

Comment: Don't call sql queries as like this. Codeigniter has very powerfull and secure database libraries and helpers and Query Builder. I recommend, allways use query builder for safer queries.

Comment: ok @MERTDOĞAN I will follow best practice as you recommend. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to pass the variable that you are sending to the **Model**.
You are not passing the variable to model that was not getting in your model's function.

Check this below that may help.

**Controller**

```
public function ajax()
{

    $size = $this->input->post('size');
    $sprice = $this->input->post('sprice');
    $eprice = $this->input->post('eprice');

    $this->load->model('ajax_model');
    $result = $this->ajax_model->ajax($size,$sprice,$eprice);


    foreach( $result as $row )
    {   
        echo $row->name.'<br>'; 
        echo $row->charge_per_hour.'<br>'; 
        echo $row->city.'<br>'; 
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function ajax($size = '',$sprice = '',$eprice = '')
{
     $query = "SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'"; 
    if($size != '')){
        $query  .= " and city in('".$size."')"; 
    }
    if(($sprice != '') && ($eprice != '')){
        $query  .=  " and charge_per_hour >='".$sprice."' and 
        charge_per_hour <='".$eprice."'"; 
    }

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result();   
}
```

Comment: yes @virb this is the mistake I was doing `$result = $this->ajax_model->ajax($size,$sprice,$eprice);` thanks brother

Comment: @Stack : Happy to help. Be careful for this small mistakes.

Comment: Don't pass POST variables to the sql queries directly without escape them like this. Allways pass parameters to the queries as variables. Codeigniter has very large and powerfull Query Builder library. I recommend allways use it in your projects.

Answer (score 2):

SO for filtering data with dropdown you need to **pass the values** of dropdown to controller i.e. city name and include it to your query and call **ajax()** at **onChange()** in view of codigniter

Answer (score 1):

Look like you do not pass your filtering arguments to ajax model. When you run the script it only execute `$query = "SELECT * from info_user Where user_status ='1'";` part. In this case the out-put will be *all data where user_status = 1.*

```
if(!empty($size)) and if(!empty($sprice) && !empty($eprice)) conditions are always false.
```

So try to inject filtering pentameters to ajax model.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction of model and controller has very big security problems about sql queries.

Allways try to use Query Builder for generate SQL queries for safer queries.

I corrected your model and controller construction how it must be below:

**Controller**

```
public function ajax(){

    $size = $this->input->post('size');
    $sprice = $this->input->post('sprice');
    $eprice = $this->input->post('eprice');

    $this->load->model('ajax_model');

    $result = $this->ajax_model->ajax( $size , $sprice , $eprice );

    foreach( $result as $row ) {   
        echo '<p>';

            echo $row['name'].'<br/>';
            echo $row['charge_per_hour'].'<br/>';
            echo $row['city'].'<br/>';

        echo '</p><hl>';//split between rows
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public function ajax( $size = null , $sprice = null , $eprice = null ){

    $this->load->database();//if not loaded automatically.

    $this->db->select('*')->from('info_user')->where('user_status',1);

    if($size){
        $size=explode(',',$size);//i think your post value for $size delimited with comma (,).
        $this->db->where_in('city',$size);
    }

    if($sprice){//$this->input->post('sprice') returns false when it is not provided. You may control it is false or not. 
        $this->db->where('charge_per_hour>=',$sprice);
    }

    if($eprice){
         $this->db->where('charge_per_hour<=',$eprice);
    }

    $result = $this->db->get();

    return $result->result_array();//using array needs a little lower system resuorces then objects.

}
```

Comment: Welcome @Stack . Best regards.